# Select results if table doesn't contain criteria

Tags: sql, oracle

**table**

```
id | term 
---+----- 
 1 | 2015
 2 | 2015
 3 | 2016
```

I have this table and want to select all 2015 results:

```
select * from table where term = 2015
```

HOWEVER, I only want it to to return 2015 results IF 2015 is the only term that shows up in the table. If it has anything else, it should not return any rows.

For example, the current table should return nothing since `id=3` has a term of `2016`. If `id=3` had a term of `2015`, I'd want it to show all `2015` results.

How can I accomplish this.

Comment: You've tagged both mysql and oracle, which are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` for this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE term = 2015 
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM table 
                  WHERE term <> 2015
                  )
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/40627/4/0)

`NOT EXISTS` evaluates to true if any records are returned by the subquery. This is a simple example, and the functionality can be expanded by correlating the subquery to the outer query.

Comment: I generally recommend avoiding correlated queries myself; in this case you can actually do way with the `term = 2015` altogether, since it will be true for every row if the second condition is true.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from `table`
where term = 2015
and not exists(select * from `table` where term != 2015)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are saying is: IF there are at least two different values in the term column, return nothing. If there is exactly one value, then return the entire table.

You didn't say if term is nullable (if it may contain nulls). Assuming it isn't, you can get your result very quickly this way:

```
select * from your_table where (select count (distinct term) from your_table) = 1;
```

(I do hope you don't have a table named literally "table"!)

If term is nullable, you need to state how you want null in the term column to be treated.